# PySpark - cumulative count per ID, ordered by date, excluding holidays

Tags: pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe made up of the following columns: `ID`,`DATE`,`ACTIVITY_FLAG`, and `HOLIDAY_FLAG`. I would like to calculate the cumulative number of days of inactivity per `ID` for each `DATE` present. This portion has already been figured out, and is named `NUMBER_OF_DAYS_SINCE_LAST_ACTIVE`, as shown in the code block below. However, what I'm unable to calculate is the number of days of inactivity, but excluding holidays. See the table in the embedded image below to see what I'm after (`NUMBER_OF_NON_HOLIDAY_DAYS_SINCE_LAST_ACTIVE`).

[image]

The code thus far is as follows:

```
df = daily_status.select(
    "ID",
    "DATE",
    "ACTIVITY_FLAG",
    "HOLIDAY_FLAG",
    F.max(F.when(daily_status["ACTIVITY_FLAG"] == 1, daily_status["DATE"])).over(windowSpec).alias("LAST_ACTIVE_DATE")
)

windowSpec = (Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy('DATE')
            .rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))

df = df.withColumn('NUMBER_OF_DAYS_SINCE_LAST_ACTIVE', F.expr("datediff(DATE, LAST_ACTIVE_DATE)"))
```